# Confused about a class nested in an ID in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to find out why my id wont beat out my class when it comes to picking a text color. I thought my id would beat out everything nested in it? I have to do #id .class {} to change a the color. I am just trying to understand what is going on here for a better understanding about how selectors work.

here's my html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- links and scripts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <!-- links and scripts -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>CSS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header style="background-color: green; color: red;">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <div id="div1">
                <p class="backi">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quisquam necessitatibus, tempora id voluptatum rerum minima dolorum voluptatem ut quo architecto laudantium aspernatur nisi eaque amet aut! Fuga, distinctio illo.</p>
                <p class="class">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quisquam necessitatibus, tempora id voluptatum rerum minima dolorum voluptatem ut quo architecto laudantium aspernatur nisi eaque amet aut! Fuga, distinctio illo.</p>
                <p class="ruu">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quisquam necessitatibus, tempora id voluptatum rerum minima dolorum voluptatem ut quo architecto laudantium aspernatur nisi eaque amet aut! Fuga, distinctio illo.</p>
                <p class="class">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quisquam necessitatibus, tempora id voluptatum rerum minima dolorum voluptatem ut quo architecto laudantium aspernatur nisi eaque amet aut! Fuga, distinctio illo.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my css code:

```
    /* 
selctor {
    property: val;
} 
*/
body {
    background-image: url(https://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero-00e10b1f.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

h1, p {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 2px blue;
    cursor: default;
}

/* p {
    color: purple;
} */

li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.class {
    color: green;
    border: none;
}
.backi {
    color: red;
}

.ruu {
    color: yellow;
}

#div1 {
    background-color: rgb(255, 192, 203, .4);
    color: black;
    border: none;
}
```

as you can see my line of code on the .css is an ID, but on my website it still shows the property from the previous class in the code. can someone explain why I have to do "element element" here instead of the ID overpowering the class.

Comment: I think it's a priority question for CSS. You can find more informations here: https://www.w3.org/wiki/Css/Training/Priority_level_of_selector

Answer (score 1):

The class will override any ID styles because the class on a specific element is more specific than targeting its parent. The `backi` class, for example, will override the `color` rule from `div1` ID because the `backi` class on an element is more specific than the `div1` ID of `backi`'s parent.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this up!! I appreciate it.